# Before test runs, fails on CCI pipeline: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null"

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, circleci

I have tried researching other topics similar to this error message ( such as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504720/jest-cannot-read-property-createevent-of-null), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579559/typeerror-cannot-read-property-createevent-of-null-react-apollo-testing), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429745/dont-know-which-tests-are-failing-with-typeerror-cannot-read-property-create) among others. ):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null

In our test suit we have a lot of mocked network calls as a single mocking layer, but there is a `throw new Error('unexpected URL')` handler for missing calls.
Also, I have verified all of my ReactTesting `findBy` queries are correctly declared with `async/await` syntax.  Sometimes the tests work, othertimes fails.

What is really curious, is the error happens ONLY in Circle CI before any tests run, it appears, based on the error message call stack:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn test:ci
yarn run v1.22.11
$ jest --ci --runInBand
/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3905
      var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3905:26)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23543:11)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
    at runWithPriority$1 (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
    at flushPassiveEffects (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23447:14)
    at Object.<anonymous>.flushWork (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:992:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1003:11)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

I have not seen this error locally, even when running the same command as my Circle CI command.

Any ideas about this, other than unhandled

Comment: Maybe you also need to check all api's are mocked or not during testing apart form async/await for findBy query

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this.  `async() await` and use expect() function and also catch the execption by new Error Object.

```
it("Should ...", async () => {
  await myFn(async () => {
    // some operations
    expect(await element.length).toBe(10).toThrow(new Error("something went wrong!"))
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding expect(something...) to the tests, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579559/typeerror-cannot-read-property-createevent-of-null-react-apollo-testing).
You should finish your test with some sort of an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but since this comes up in google:

I tried lots of different fixes suggested in different stackoverflow answers, but what worked for me was simply increasing the default timeout limit by adding the `--testTimeout=20000` argument to jest's command line options.
(after --runInBand, in circleCi's config.yml)

The value of 20000 is just a guess.